# Difference between tahriman and tanzihan makrooh

Tags: hanafi, usool-ul-fiqh, makruh

> It is understood from that expression that to remove the hairs on the
>   back and chest is not haram or tahriman makrooh for Hanafis. It can
>   only be tanzihan makrooh, contrary to decency.

I was reading an article online and came accross these terms, I know what is makrooh but have no idea that there were two types.

So what is the difference between tahriman and tanzihan makrooh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both classes of *makruh* acts are considered reprehensible and should be avoided (and doing so is a blessed act which would be rewarded); the main difference between a *makruh tanzih* act and a *makruh tahrim* act is whether performing them would be actually be considered *sinful*.  On a scale of severity, they would look like this:

**Mubah** < **Makruh Tanzih** < **Makruh Tahrim** < **Haram**

Performing a *makruh tanzih* act is strongly discouraged, but would not necessarily warrant punishment in the hereafter (although to my understanding, many scholars claim that *consistently and repeatedly* performing *makruh tanzih* acts would be considered sinful, even if the single acts themselves would not). If something is *makruh tahrim*, on the other hand, it *would* be considered sinful and punished appropriately in the hereafter, but they are not so severe as to take one out of the fold of Islam (as would, for example, rejecting a *haram* ruling).

Comment: @goldpseudo Correct but without references.

Comment: @servant OP didn't ask for references, and since this is just a basic definition of terms, i don't see why references are at all necessary.